# Passing a function down to a component through props - REACT

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass the 'handleItemClick' function from the 'Dropdown' component, down to they 'Team' component, however, I can't get it past the 'List' component. The strange thing is, is that when I log the props inside the 'List' it says that 'itemClick' is in the 'this.props' object and yet when I set it as a prop on the 'Team' component it says "Cannot read property 'itemClick' of undefined".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Dropdown Component:

```
var Dropdown = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            display: false
        };  
    },
    handleClick: function(e){
        this.setState({display: !this.state.display})
    },
    handleItemClick: function(e){
        console.log("Something");
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="dropdown">
                <Button whenClicked={this.handleClick} className="btn-default" title={this.props.data.title} number={this.props.data.teams.length} />
                <List teams={this.props.data.teams} display={this.state.display} itemClick={this.handleItemClick}/>
            </div>
        );   
    }
});
```

List Component:

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        console.log(this.props)
        var teams = this.props.teams.map(function(team){
            return <Team key={team} team={team} teamChoice={this.props.itemClick}  />
        });

        var displayStyle = {
            display: this.props.display ? 'block' : 'none'
        };

        return (
            <ul style={displayStyle} className="dropdown-menu">
                {teams}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post your Team component?

Comment: You're probably saying `this.props.itemClick` instead of `this.props.teamChoice`. Maybe just name the prop the same thing `<Team itemClick={this.props.itemClick}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kristofen44 was close:

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) loses the `this` from your parent scope inside it's callback.  But the function includes a variable input for accessing `this` within it:

```
var teams = this.props.teams.map(function(team){
    return <Team key={team} team={team} teamChoice={this.props.itemClick}  />
}, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think the error resides in List Component's render function when you map team to generate nodes. the map callback function loses the context 'this'. I think you have to bind the callback function to 'this' explicitly.
Like so :

```
var teams = this.props.teams.map(function(team){
    return <Team key={team} team={team} teamChoice={this.props.itemClick}  />
}.bind(this)); // <------
```

BTW, being quite new to react, I don't know if it's good practice to pass an whole object to the attribute 'key' of your Team component... I wonder if it's not better to just pass an id or something like that..

Hope it helps